# Div alignment in a bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am having trouble getting vertical `div`s to line up correctly. There seems to be something pushing down the first column of `div`s. Here is the jsfiddle for it:

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39011/)

The problem is in the modal popup, so just click the Details button to launch the modal dialog.

Why is the first column being pushed down from the top? I am tempted to just put it all in a table and be done with it.

Comment: You need to declare a `vertical-align` value on your *inline* elements, **e.g:** `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: See updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39017/

Comment: Yep. That will definitely work. I am curious what was causing it to not be aligned the same as the other two columns. They had similar heights. Just seemed like a dramatic shift for some reason. Maybe some responsive aspect was kicking in. Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 1):

use vertical-align:top in div phase,voltage,current

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown active">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Getting started <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download">Download Bootstrap</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Examples</li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template">Basic template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/">Starter template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/">Grids</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/">Jumbotron</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/">Navbar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/">Sign-in page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/">Sticky footer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/">Offcanvas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/">Carousel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/">Theme</a></li>                        
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Compatibility</li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration">Migrating from 2.x to 3.0</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers">Browser support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties">Third party support</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/components">Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/customize">Customize</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="row text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Details</a>
</div>    
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="motor-1">Power Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="ipac-details">
                    <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                        <div id="phase" style="float:none;display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;"><h2>Phase</h2></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;height:131px;"><h2>A</h2></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;height:131px;"><h2>B</h2></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;height:131px;"><h2>C</h2></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;height:239px;"><h2>Angles</h2></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="voltage" style="float:none;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;"><h2>Voltage</h2></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;" id="voltage-a-gauge"></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;" id="voltage-b-gauge"></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;" id="voltage-c-gauge"></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;" id="voltage-phase-gauge"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="current" style="float:none;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;"><h2>Current</h2></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;" id="current-a-gauge"></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;" id="current-b-gauge"></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;" id="current-c-gauge"></div>
                            <div style="border:solid 1px red;" id="current-phase-gauge"></div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-collapse collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#harmonic-analysis" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#harmonic-analysis">
                                Harmonic Analysis
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-collapse collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pf-analysis" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#pf-analysis">
                                Power Factor Analysis
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse" id="harmonic-analysis">
                        <div class="well">
                            Harmonic Analysis details go here.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse" id="pf-analysis">
                        <div class="well">
                            PF details go here.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: left;` to align `<div id="phase">`